# datagridTemplatecolumn does not fire event textChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an event inside a column that is not triggered.

Inside MainWindow.xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Remise %">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=remise}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=remise, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=isArticleDivers}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In Mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     // Do some code .... 
}
```

How i can make a column with textchanged event properly?

Comment: This is of course because DataGridTemplateColumn is not a part of the same visual tree. So routed event doesn't route in the way you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand...

Comment: @ebelair according to your code it should work. give me team viewer i can check

Comment: Could it be that the textbox doesn't lose focus, hence the event isn't fired?